# Andorid Customize ListView makes a few row to be special

Tags: android, listview

I have a DrawerLayout, my DrawerLayout currently display a listview that have an image and a text, and everything just works fine

Now, I decides to add an header in my DrawerLayout and add a special field for a few Rows in my listview

Thank you

this image tells everything about what i want to do:

http://8pic.ir/images/als4ye1elyo35tpju7hq.png

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/MainDrawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/MainDrawerFrame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ListView android:id="@+id/MainDrawerListView"
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:background="@color/DrawerBackGround" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

drawer_listview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="45dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/DrawerIcon"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/DrawerText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textColor="@color/DrawerFontColor"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/DrawerIcon"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/DrawerIcon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

CustomListAdapter.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
private final Activity ActivityContext;
private final String[] ItemName;
private final Integer[] ImageID;

public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, String[] itemname, Integer[] imgid)
{
    super(context, R.layout.drawer_listview, itemname);

    this.ActivityContext = context;
    this.ItemName = itemname;
    this.ImageID = imgid;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View Unused1, ViewGroup Unused2)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = ActivityContext.getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_listview, null);

    ImageView DrawerIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.DrawerIcon);
    TextView DrawerText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.DrawerText);

    Typeface FontFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(ActivityContext.getAssets(), "Yekan.ttf");
    DrawerText.setTypeface(FontFace);

    DrawerIcon.setImageResource(ImageID[position]);
    DrawerText.setText(ItemName[position]);

    return view;
};
}
```

MainActivity.java
http://paste.ubuntu.com/15237990/

Answer (score 0):

Do you want your header to scroll off the top of the screen when the user scrolls the listview? If so, simply add a header to the listview using the [addHeaderView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean)) API.

If you want your header to stay in place, add it in the XML

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Header text"/>
    <ListView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```